# How do I read this function in English?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image: Pic of Formula]
$$
\theta_3 (q)^4 = P\Big( (1-q^{2n}) \cdot(1+q^{2n-1})^2 \quad n = 1 \ldots \in f \Big)^4= \eta\frac{(-q)^8} \eta (q^2)^4
$$

The instructions were to "Determine the Integer Sequences." However, there is more information given to the problem that I haven't put here because I just need to be able to know what I'm reading.

Thank you in advance.

The 3 next to theta is supposed to be small but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I don't understand the formula you are writing, especially the $\in$ symbol. Is your question written on paper or found on the Internet?

Comment: Yes, I'll upload an image.

Comment: The far RHS is equal to $q^{16}$ so if we are dealing with only  real numbers , then  $\theta_3(q)^4=q^{16}\iff \theta_3(q)=\pm q^4.$... The meaning of the middle term is unclear. It is not in standard notation. Maybe it means $ [\;\prod_{n\in f}((1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1})^2)\; ]^4.$  (Maybe not)... And it is not stated what $ f$ is.

Comment: Go to the Help page, to the Help Center. Under "Our Model", go to "How can I format mathematics here"?

Answer (score 1):

The formula doesn't make sense as it stands. The problem seems though to amount to "express $\theta_3(q)^4$ in terms of the Dedekind $\eta$-function".

We have, by the Jacobi Triple product,
$$\begin{align}
\theta_3(q)^4&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n})^4(1+q^{2n-1})^8
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-(-q)^n)^8}{(1-q^{2n})^4}=\frac{\eta(-q)^8}{\eta(q^2)^4}
\end{align}$$
if we define
$$\eta(q)=q^{1/24}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)$$
and fudge the factor of a root of unity somehow.

Comment: oooh1 THANK YOU! This helps a lot.